# jquery: why can I only get the first data attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
var status = $('meta').data('status'), 
    id = $('meta').data('id'), 
    details = $('meta').data('details');           
    console.log(status, id, details);
```

and the following HTML,

```
<head>
    <meta data-status="stopped" > 
    <meta data-id="0001" >
    <meta data-details="Example details" >
```

and only the `status` variable is printed to console and the `id` and `details` variables are printed as 'undefined'. But if I rearrange the meta tags to:

```
<head>
        <meta data-id="0001" >
        <meta data-status="stopped" > 
        <meta data-details="Example details" >
```

Then only the `id` variable will print to console.

What am I missing?

Comment: which jQuery version you are using

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$('meta')` returns jQuery array-like object containing all three `meta` elements.
`$('meta').data('status')` returns `data-status` attribute value of the **first** element, and it works properly.
However, `$('meta').data('id')` tries to read data attribute `id` of the first element too, but there isn't.

You either need to combine all data attributes into a single meta.

```
<meta data-status="stopped" data-id="0001" data-details="Example details"/>
```

This way, you can do (assuming that it is the first `meta` tag in your document)

```
var status = $('meta').data('status'), 
    id = $('meta').data('id'), 
    details = $('meta').data('details');
```

Another way is to use attributes in selectors:

```
<meta data-status="stopped" > 
<meta data-id="0001" >
<meta data-details="Example details" >

var status = $('meta[data-status]').data('status'), 
    id = $('meta[data-id]').data('id'), 
    details = $('meta[data-details]').data('details');
```

Answer (score 6):

The **[`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** method  return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements so it would always try to get data-* value from the first element and which is undefined.

Use [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to get meta tag with a particular data-* attribute.

```js
var status = $('meta[data-status]').data('status'),
  id = $('meta[data-id]').data('id'),
  details = $('meta[data-details]').data('details');
console.log(status, id, details)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta data-status="stopped">
<meta data-id="0001">
<meta data-details="Example details">
```

Comment: This is such backwards behavior for jquery, where every other selector always returns an array of items.